# How to index from a list nested in an array?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a variable which returns this:

```
array(list([0, 1, 2]), dtype=object)
```

How do I index from this? Everything I have tried throws an error.

For reference, some code that would produce this variable.

```
import xarray as xr
x = xr.DataArray(
    [[0,1,2],
    [3,4]]
)
x
```

I guess before anyone asks, I am trying to test if xarray's DataArrays is a suitable way for me to store session-based data containing multiple recordings saved as vectors/1D arrays, but each recording/array can vary in length. That is why the DataArray doesn't have even dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: have you already tried the canonical methods of indexing and slicing with xarray? http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html

Comment: _"Everything I have tried throws an error"_ so please, [edit][ your question and show us what have you tried… thank you

Comment: @Carlo yes that was the first thing I tried, didn't work but the submitted answer here did work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code given by you to create the `x` variable. I was able to retrieve the lists using following code:

```
for arr in x:
    print(arr.item())
```

Basically, you have to call `.item()` on that array to retrieve the inner list.